# Coloring individual faces of shape in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm extending a simple example which displays a rotating cube, I'd like to change the colour of individual faces, but not having any luck. What's wrong with this code? Thanks

```
$(function(){
    var camera, scene, renderer,
    geometry, material, mesh;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 800;

        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 500, 70, 70 );

        material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
            color: 0xff0000,
            shading: THREE.FlatShading, 
            overdraw: true 
        } );
        material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
            color: 0x00ff00, 
            shading: THREE.FlatShading, 
            overdraw: true 
        } );
        geometry.materials = [material_1, material_2];
        geometry.faces[0].materialIndex = 0;
        geometry.faces[1].materialIndex = 1;
        geometry.faces[2].materialIndex = 0;
        geometry.faces[3].materialIndex = 1;
        geometry.faces[4].materialIndex = 0;
        geometry.faces[5].materialIndex = 1;
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );

        scene.add( mesh );
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
    }
    function render() {
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.05;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an array of materials to the MeshFaceMaterial constructor as an argument.

Instead of:

```
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
```

You should have:

```
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( geometry.materials ) );
```

Comment: I think it should be var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [ material_1, material_2 ] ));

Comment: The var statement for mesh is included near the top of the document, outside the init function.   This makes it scoped within the entire jQuery 'ready' function so it can be accessible to the render function later on.  Adding var in front of mesh = new THREE.Mesh( ... ) would create a new variable named mesh that pointed to the THREE.Mesh, but whose scope was limited to the init function. Since the global mesh variable would remain unassigned render's attempts to change the mesh's rotation would cause errors.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I was testing this solution and found that the box geometry has more than 5 faces (2 triangles for each side of the box) so you need to remember to set the materialIndex field for all faces. Hope that helps someone.